# React-intl : how to provide a default language if a particular msg for other languages do not exist?

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

So I'm trying to create an application which dynamically takes translations from another (custom) API but there are times that this API might not have translations for English. However, it will always have messages for the default language. `defaultMessage` in `FormattedMessage` will not work since the "id" is dynamic in nature.

Any clue on how I can do this?